# OpenAI gym installing error

Tags: python-3.x, pip, openai-gym

I've tried to install OpenAi Gym on Windows with pip, but 2 errors raised.

First I cloned the repository and executed:

> git clone https://github.com/openai/gym.git
>
> cd gym
>
> pip install -e .

Until here all good. I can test the first environments.

But When I try the full installation,

> pip install -e '.[all]'

I got the errors:

> Failed building wheel for Box2D-kengz
>
> Failed building wheel for mujoco-py
>
> Command "c:\users\salva\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\salva\AppData\Loc
>   al\Temp\pip-build-g8mb7_qr\atari-py\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\ n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\salva\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uayfrm 4q-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed
>   --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\salva\A ppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-g8mb7_qr\atari-py\

It seems that I can't install the whole package.

My pip version is:

> pip 9.0.1

Any thought?? Thanks!!

Comment: I am also having the same issue: I get  `Failed building wheel for Box2D-kengz` and `Failed building wheel for atari-py`. Did you figure out anything?